# How to compare and sum different columns in a single table mysql

Tags: mysql, join, sum

```
I have a table with some duplicate stock ids and release date.The table table data is like below.

|STOCK_ID       |QTY| release_date|
-----------------------------------
|4046228009711    |12 | 25.02.2015  |
|4046228009711    |3  | 21.12.2014  |
|4046228009711    |13 | 21.12.2014  |
|4046228009711    |5  | 21.12.2014  |
------------------------------------

Now i want to sum the quantity of same stock id and same released_date and segregate records based on the released_date.
So the  out put should be like this.This is the expected output

|STOCK_ID       |QTY| release_date|
-----------------------------------
|4046228009711    |12 | 25.02.2015  |
|4046228009711    |21 | 21.12.2014  |
-----------------------------------
```

To achieve this i tried with the below query.
    For this i inserted the same data in a temporary table .

```
SELECT t1.STOCK_ID,t1.`released_date
(SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM 
table1 t1 
WHERE h1.STOCK_ID = t2.STOCK_ID AND t1.released_date = t2.released_date
) AS 'Bestand'
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.STOCK_ID = t2.STOCK_ID 
GROUP BY t1.STOCK_ID

But i am getting the below output

|STOCK_ID       |QTY| release_date|
-----------------------------------
|4046228009711    |12 | 25.02.2015 |
-----------------------------------
```

Can any one help me where i am doing mistake? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done as

```
select 
STOCK_ID,
sum(QTY) as QTY,
release_date
from table_name
group by STOCK_ID,release_date
```